# why using uint for account balance in solidity?

Tags: solidity

This question may have been asked many times but I did not find a good answer online. The account balance is usually represented as `fixed decimal` in other language but in `Solidity` it is `uint`. How an integer can be used for account balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fundamental to Ethereum as solidity's base unit is `wei`, which is indivisible and the smallest unit in Ethereum, thus making it unnecessary to be denoted with decimals.

`1 ether = 1e18 wei` and for more detail on ethereum units, check out the official [documentation.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html)